# Get most recent modified time of a folder recursively with PHP

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to php and any advice is appreciated.

I have written a code to the most recently updated time for a folder in php.
Can you please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

And here the code I use:

```
function get_m_time_dir ($directory)
{
$last_modified_time = 0;
$handler = opendir ($directory);
while ($file = readdir ($handler))
{
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_file ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file))
    {
        $filemtime = filemtime ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        if ($filemtime > $last_modified_time)
        {
            $last_modified_time = $filemtime;
        }
    } else
    {
        $filemtime = get_m_time_dir ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        if ($filemtime > $last_modified_time)
        {
            $last_modified_time = $filemtime;
        }
    }
}
return $last_modified_time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

It depends on whether you care for the deleted files or not. If you do, you should also check the modification time for the directory itself, not only files in it.

The code itself could be also improved:

- you can remove the duplicated condition
- which in turn, can be substituted with `max()` function.
- also you can utilize the `glob()` function that can save you that boring `$file == '..'` condition, as well as other unnecessary code.

So in the end the code could be

```
function get_m_time_dir ($directory)
{
    $last_modified_time = 0;
    $dirmtime = filemtime ($directory);
    foreach (glob("$directory/*") as $file)
    {
        if (is_file ($file))
        {
            $filemtime = filemtime ($file);
        } else {
            $filemtime = get_m_time_dir ($file);
        }
        $last_modified_time = max($filemtime, $dirmtime, $last_modified_time);
    }
    return $last_modified_time;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using SPL's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) for this. This would eliminate the need for the function itself to be called recursively (which is generally a good thing since PHP does not perform tail call recursion optimization).

```
function get_m_time_dir($path)
{
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
        $path,
        FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | 
        FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | 
        FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    );
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        $directory,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST 
    );
    $resultFile = $iterator->current();
    foreach($iterator as $file) {
        if ($file->getMtime() > $resultFile->getMtime()) {
            $resultFile = $file;
        }
    }
    return $resultFile->getMtime();
}
```

Note that inside the `array_reduce()` closure, you are working with [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) objects which provide a wealth of information about the individual file they represent. Also note that this function would throw an `UnexpectedValueException` if the path provided to instantiate the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` is not valid.

I would recommend gaining some familiarity with the [SPL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) as, in addition to providing great object-oriented means for interacting with the file system, this library provides a collection of fundamental classes that any PHP developer should be aware of.

Comment: PHP Warning:  array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @YourCommonSense Would have guess that class implementing `Traversable` could go into `array_reduce()`, but apparently not :)  Updated to reflect simple foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to test, whether this function is checking directories. Looks like not - it doesn't change the output if I delete a file.

Comment: @YourCommonSense It certainly should. Are you using a FAT file system (like Windows) where directory mtime does not change on directory content changes (i.e. renaming, adding, deleting files)?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually realized I didn't specify the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` on `RecursiveIteratorIterator` so it was only doing leaf nodes previously.

Comment: Thank you. On my test bench (which is Debian-based), the current version doesn't reflect the file deletion in the main directory but does for a subdirectory. I.e. if there is a `dir`  with a `subdir` inside and I am running this function against `dir`, it shows a file change if I delete a file from `subdir` but doesn't if I delete a file from `dir`. And if I run it against `subdir`, it doesn't see the deleted files, only showing the modification time for the most recently edited file

Comment: @YourCommonSense The original code does not consider the base path passed to the method. If that were intended usage, I suppose one could remove the skip dots flag to get info on the base directory.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can also do like

```
function get_m_time_dir ($directory)
{
$last_modified_time = 0;
$handler = opendir ($directory);
while ($file = readdir ($handler))
{
    if (is_file ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file) && !($file == '.' || $file == '..'))
    {
        $filemtime = filemtime ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        if ($filemtime > $last_modified_time)
        {
            $last_modified_time = $filemtime;
        }
    } else
    {

       if !($file == '.' || $file == '..'){
             $filemtime = get_m_time_dir ($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
          if ($filemtime > $last_modified_time)
          {
             $last_modified_time = $filemtime;
          }
       }
    }
}
return $last_modified_time;
}
```

Comment: You should offer some explanation in your answer, not just a code rewrite.  What did you change?  Why did you change it?